# How to filter parent object by it's children id?

Tags: typescript, angular7, ecmascript-5, ngrx-store

I am getting backend response like this:

```
{
  "ReturnModel": {
    "Id": 20,
    "Name": "tserror.JPG,typeIssue.JPG",
    "Description": "testing",
    "SubjectId": 100001,
    "SubjectTypeId": 100001,
    "SubjectLevelId": 100001,
    "SubjectOptionId": 100001,
    "LanguageId": 100001,
    "BlobFileUpload": [
      {
        "FileId": 27,
        "FileName": "tserror_20190410110826.JPG",
        "FileDescription": "Upload",
        "CourseId": 20,
        "CourseFileUpload": null
      },
      {
        "FileId": 28,
        "FileName": "typeIssue_20190410110826.JPG",
        "FileDescription": "Upload",
        "CourseId": 20,
        "CourseFileUpload": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

From the above json value, I need to filter the parent from it's `BlobFileUpload` - `FileId`. For that, I tried the following, but not works. any suggest me the correct approach?

```
case fileActions.RemoveFileSuccess.TYPE :

            const fileId = (<fileActions.RemoveFileSuccess>action).payload.Id;

            return {
                ...state,
                uploadedFiles : state.uploadedFiles.filter(file => file.BlobFileUpload.filter(blob => blob.FileId !== fileId))
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is `state.uploadedFiles.filter(file => file.BlobFileUpload.some(blob => blob.FileId !== fileId))`

[`Array.protptype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) checks if **any** item in the array is truthful for the provided predicate and returns a boolean.

[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) expects a predicate which returns a boolean, but `filter` itself returns an array and an array is always truthy. That's why it was not filtering for you.